# diminished chord in degree

Tags: jazz

I would like to write dowb a jazz grid in "Degree notation" in order to make it "tonality free", but i'm stucked with a problem.

The song is billie's bounce and i don't know how to write the diminished chord after the 4th degree (see picture).

Also i don't know what's the fonction of that chords and what makes it so powerfull on this progression.

Thank you!

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IV#o or Four sharp diminished.  I'd choose that since the letter name indicates degree.  Since Bb is the fourth of F (and you've indicated F and the I) B natural is the sharp fourth rather than a flat fifth.  Of course you could use substitutions to replace the diminished chord with something else.  If these are real book changes as opposed to an original score those are seldom exact (or even correct).

Comment: Of course! This is it =) I've completly forgettent that you could put alterations to the roman number. Now it's all clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It certainly won't be IVo, as that would make it Bbo. And the same goes for Vo, making it Co. Out of diminished chords, that actually leaves the one for which you search. In F, it's called (here) Bo, but the same notes occur in Io. Often with a dim chord, the four notes can be played in any order. I often see in charts, say, Bo, written as a chord symbol, but with either F, Ab, B (Cb here!) or D written in as the lowest (bass) note. So, I'd go for Io. Jazz players will often choose how they voice chords anyhow, so, although it may be slightly technically inaccurate, the correct notes will come out. Only in a different order...(Eric Morecombe!).

Your 'degree notation' bears a striking resemblance to NNS.

Comment: I'll go for Io since you're right, the notes are the same =) Thank you

Edit : What is NNS? ^^

Comment: NNS= Nashville Numbering System, where instead of a chord chart in a particular key, songs' accompaniments in chords is written in Roman Numerals, so session musos can simply read the RN, and chord types, and transpose instantly. Something like you're doing!

Comment: Ohh very good, i couldn't put a name on this system, it was just a simple "Scale degree notation" to me =) 

I've learned twice much as i was hoping to! Thanks!

Comment: Have a good look into it. I've used a bastardised version for a good 50 yrs, but don't like certain bits, like '-' for minor. Mainly as in handwritten stuff, it's too easy to miss or worse, see a mark that's not there intentionally! Tend to use lower case for minors. Or simple 'm'.

Comment: Well, new material to learn \o/ I like it. See you Tim

Comment: Seems like I now have a -15 score for this. But it's not shown here. Glitch?

Comment: @Doktor Mayhem - Perhaps a mod. could reconcile the -15 for this answer. Don't care any more about downvotes - only the reasons given! But here, the sums don't add up ( or even subtract).